# How to correctly use $nick in mIRC msg?

Tags: mirc

So I'm starting to get really familiar with mIRC and the powers that it can do, however I have a small problem. So the basic code is:

```
on *:text:!bet *:#aaron128l { msg $chan $nick, Your bet wasn't counted! }
```

However the problem, arises bacause the output is:

```
Your bet wasn't counted!
```

It is mainly missing the $nick. I'm aware the problem is with the `$nick,` so how can I have it with the output being:

```
Aaron128l, Your bet wasn't counted!
```

I'm also aware that `$nick ,` will work. However, that will add the additional space. To be `Aaron128l , Your bet wasn't counted!` Which isn't desired.

What am I missing? Also sorry for the near awful wording of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$nick` is an identifier, which means it must exist between bits of whitespace , or within the parameters of another identifier, to function.  Translated to code, that means..

```
on *:text:!bet *:#aaron128l { msg $chan $nick $+ , Your bet wasn't counted! }
```

As you note, I made the addition of `$+`, which combines two items together; you will need this here in order for your code to work.  Otherwise, mirc interprets the comma as being apart of the `$nick` identifier, which then of course fails to parse(check your status window for some error in that regard).